# DatagramChannel not receiving any bytes on Android

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, selector

**Update**
I tried the same implementation, but this time with ServerSocketChannel/SocketChannel. This works on Android. It seems that I am somehow having 100% packet loss over UDP on Android. Does anyone have thoughts on the cause for this? (It is not a WiFi-issue. The UDP client works from my notebook.)

**Original**
I am having trouble receiving packets in an Android application. The Android application is able to send data to the desktop server, who replies immediately, but always receives zero bytes. The same code works when I use it as a desktop client application.

My Android application has the INTERNET permission. I also tried it with NETWORK, CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. That made no difference, sadly.

Tried it both on a device and in an emulator.

Below is the code and a sample of the output.

MainActivity:

```
private Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    thread = new Thread(new Client());
    thread.start();
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "NET";
private static final String IP = "--.---.---.--";
private static final int PORT = 6543;

private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

private boolean running;

public Client() {
    running = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        final Selector selector = Selector.open();
        final DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
        datagramChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        datagramChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        datagramChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP, PORT));

        running = true;
        while (running) {
            selector.select();

            final Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                final SelectionKey key = keys.next();

                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    handleRead(key);
                }

                if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable()) {
                    handleWrite(key);
                }

                keys.remove();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void handleRead(final SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    final DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    byteBuffer.clear();
    final SocketAddress from = channel.receive(byteBuffer);
    byteBuffer.flip();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Received %d bytes from %s", byteBuffer.limit(), from));

    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}

private void handleWrite(final SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    final DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    byteBuffer.clear();
    byteBuffer.putInt(1234);
    byteBuffer.flip();

    final SocketAddress to = new InetSocketAddress(IP, PORT);
    final int bytes = channel.send(byteBuffer, to);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Send %d bytes to %s", bytes, to));

    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
private static final int PORT = 6543;

private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

private SocketAddress from;

private boolean running;

public Server() {
    from = null;
    running = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        final Selector selector = Selector.open();
        final DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
        datagramChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        datagramChannel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
        datagramChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        datagramChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));

        running = true;
        while (running) {
            selector.selectNow();

            final Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                final SelectionKey key = keys.next();

                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    handleRead(key);
                }

                if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable()) {
                    handleWrite(key);
                }

                keys.remove();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void handleRead(final SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    final DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    byteBuffer.clear();
    from = channel.receive(byteBuffer);
    byteBuffer.flip();

    System.out.println(String.format("Received %d bytes from %s", byteBuffer.limit(), from));

    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}

private void handleWrite(final SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    final DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    if (from != null) {
        byteBuffer.clear();
        byteBuffer.putInt(1234);
        byteBuffer.flip();

        final int bytes = channel.send(byteBuffer, from);

        System.out.println(String.format("Send %d bytes to %s", bytes, from));
    }

    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Thread(new Server()).start();
}
}
```

Client output:

> Send 4 bytes to /--.---.---.--:6543
>   Received 0 bytes from null
>   Send 4 bytes to /--.---.---.--:6543
>   Received 0 bytes from null

Server output:

> Received 4 bytes from /--.---.---.--:52974
>   Send 4 bytes to /--.---.---.--:52974
>   Received 4 bytes from /--.---.---.--:52974
>   Send 4 bytes to /--.---.---.--:52974

Comment: Why are you calling setReuseAddress() in the client when you aren't calling bind()? Why are you sleeping? Why are you calling connect() and also specifying the target address in send()? Why are you specifying %s when the corresponding argument is an integer?

Comment: @EJP Didn't remove it after copying the demo code from the server code I guess. Just sleeping so I'm not flooding my console with the output. Actually using connect with read/write fixed the issue for me on Android. Any idea why though? Since UDP is essentially connectionless, I would assume that read/write just calls receive/read with a saved SocketAddress. (Maybe the Android jvm just handles it differently somehow)

Comment: `DatagramChannel.receive()` doesn't work on Android 5.0 and above, you need to use `DatagramChannel.read()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have a few questions for you, if you have a second: Do you know if there is any more information about this issue somewhere, like an official statement, or a bug report? Is this on purpose? Is it possible using just `.read()` to also receive packets on some port from any remote socket or do I need to first connect to a specific one? In other words, is it still possible with this to run something like a TFTP server (which listens on UDP port 69) on the phone, for example? Does `DatagramSocket.receive(...)` still work? Thank you.

Comment: @markus unfortunately all I remember about this is that this caused a problem with UDP using kryonet